# Handling Events in TS - No overload

Tags: typescript, event-handling, dom-events

I have the **_onClick** function, which listens to click or touch events depending on the device, so my event is MouseEvent or TouchEvent type.

In useEffect, addEventListener complains with the message: No overload matches this call (2769).

How can I properly write this down to avoid TS error?

```
const _onClick = (e: MouseEvent & TouchEvent):void => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const positionX = (e.touches && e.touches[0].pageX) || e.clientX;
};


useEffect(() => {
  if (tablet) {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', _onClick);
  }
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', _onClick);
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `e` can be either `MouseEvent` or `TouchEvent` you shoudl use a union type (`|`) not an intersection type (`&`). An intersection type would mean `e` were `MouseEvent` and `TouchEvent` at the same time.

To differentiate between the two cases (and access specific properties to each type) you can use an `in` type guard:

```
const _onClick = (e: MouseEvent | TouchEvent): void => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const positionX = 'touches' in e ? e.touches[0].pageX : e.clientX;
};

declare const tablet: boolean;
if (tablet) {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', _onClick);
} else {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', _onClick);
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+uAwgGwJbANYwLwwBQCmAXDALIgCuEBAogG4FiwA+MAKpcABb2NQCUJOiFQATHAD4YAbwCwAKBhKYBAHQAHAE4EGTACIEAZgEMKyKHn4BuBQuUxQkWOpARUUVOAAaOGAHIoTi4CCD8YVDAVGAB+FVVAim4QgG0ABgBdDWMAcwIfEjVgND4vG3kAXzKFUQIi420HcGgYKGMAI2QCKBI2kBBO4zAy1EN8Vo6u-hk7ZVEQYAoAWz5VY1FRXiYAGVRoRgJNPACg6HqoPwAaeCQ0TGsFcpVkamnFWfmllbWN3SgdvbAByOi0o1DmAHcwJdrmAUOgMPcKkA)